# C# smtp doesn't want to send an email

Tags: c#, smtp

when sending an email, I get an exception:
Sending mail failed.
I've set the host to "smtp.gmail.com" and port to 587 but it doesn't work.
Code:

```
public void SendActivationLink(string email)
    {
        using (MailMessage mail = new MailMessage())
        {

            SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
            smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
            smtpClient.Port = 587;
            MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
            MailAddress from = new MailAddress("myemail@gmail.com", "Voc");

            message.From = from;
            message.To.Add(email);
            message.Subject = "Title";
            message.Body = "Jello"; 
            smtpClient.Host = "smtp.gmail.com"; 
            smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            smtpClient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            smtpClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("myemail@gmail.com", "mypassword");
            try
            {
                smtpClient.SendAsync(message, email);
            }
            catch (SmtpException ex)
            {

                throw new ApplicationException("exeption" + ex.Message);

            }


        }
```

Comment: Exception Message/Stack Trace?

Comment: Have you enabled, in the account's Security panel, `Less secure app access`?. Also, try port 25 (it auto-switches). Plus, check, in the Remarks section of [SmtpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient), the **Important!** note.

Comment: Do you have two-factor authentication set up in your Gmail account? If yes, then you need to create an application password: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en

Comment: I have disabled two-factor authentication